# .htaccess infinite loop on 404 in subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, subdirectory, wildcard-subdomain

I got a little problem concerning a project I'm working on.
I want to maintain only one .htaccess file in the root folder of this project. It is modular, so there are many different subfolders. My current .htacccess looks as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On

#strip www from domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

#ignore existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Check if query string exists
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

# Check that the request is not for an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

The problem is that every 404 error in a subfolder leads to an infinite loop because it looks for i.e. http://mydomain.tld/modules/index.php?p=404 instead of http://mydomain.tld/index.php?p=404 .
I know I could hardcode the URL in my .htaccess, but the problem is that it's kind of a community-hosting platform, where the community is specified dynamically via the subdomain and I want to keep the request in that specific subdomain.
Is there any possible way to force the .htaccess to use the index.php in the root-folder without giving the absolute url?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include your rewrite rules in your question. The `[...]` part is what is causing the loop.

Comment: Done that. I removed them while testing and the error occured anyways, so I didn't think they were important...

Comment: Is this complete .htaccess since your last rewrite condition is orphan.